# Как поместить изображение на кнопке(справа)?

Tags: android, android-button

Есть кнопка с векторным изображением, но оно находится слева, как сделать чтобы изображение стало справа.

((Button) findViewById(R.id.send)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_feedblack_send), null, null, null);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

передайте его как третий аргумент

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.send)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_feedblack_send), null);
```

вот какие аргументы имеет этот метод

```
public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

или в xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Action"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_feedblack_send"/>
```